# java springboot how to autowired in prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus

i have a controller for my http url with autowired event for my database (everything work fine)

```
@RestController public class CalculateDistance {

@Autowired MyDatabase mydb

some code

@GetMapping(value = "/url")
public Strng get() {
    return mydb.fetch("my query");
}
```

now i have the same autowired but its not working, i get null instead of my object

```
 @Component public class PrometheusMonitor {

     @Autowired MyDatabase mydb

     public PrometheusMonitor(MeterRegistry registry) {
         meterRegistry = registry;

         mydb =  null ...
```

i get an exception becuase mydb = null

but it works for my http controller

Comment: Do you create a PrometheusMonitor with `new`? If so, then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Comment: no since springboot does it, i followed this https://blog.autsoft.hu/defining-custom-metrics-in-a-spring-boot-application-using-micrometer/

Comment: Ah. OK. I see it now. You can't expect Spring to have autowired the field of an object if the object doesn't exist yet. And since you're trying to access `mydb` in the constructor, the object isn't constructed yet. Stop using field injection. Everything would be much clearer if you posted actual code, instead of pseudo-code.

Comment: @JBNizet so what should I do?

Comment: Stop using field injection. Use constructor injection. Inject the mydb using the constructor, just as you're doing it to inject registry.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry, I am not an expert, can you give an example, im no familar with consutrct injector

Comment: Remove the Autowired annotation on the field. Add an argument of type MyDatabase to your constructor, just like you're already doing it with MeterRegistry. It's just a constructor. You construct an object by passing what it needs as constructor arguments. That's constructor injection.

Comment: thanks ill try  that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put into works what @JB said,

Constructor Injection will:

- Supports immutability
- State Safe. The object is instantiated to a full state or is not instantiated at all.
- Easy to tests and mocks object injections
- Constructors are more suitable for mandatory dependencies

**IntelliJ IDEA support:**

[image: Intellij support]

So for your example, you need to pass it in the constructor like this:

```
 @Component public class PrometheusMonitor {

 @Autowired
 public PrometheusMonitor(MeterRegistry registry, MyDatabase mydb) {
     meterRegistry = registry;

     assertNotNull(mydb);

     // rest of code
```

Read more about this:

https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/

Comment: im am missing the autowire at the function Danke dir

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you dont doing the following:

```
PrometheusMonitor monitor = new PrometheusMonitor(registry);
```

that will not property autowire your database and would give you errors if you try to autowire the `PrometheusMonitor` unless you have a bean created for `MeterRegistry`

Here are things you can do

1) Have a no-argument constructor for `PrometheusMonitor`

```
 @Component public class PrometheusMonitor {

   @Autowired MyDatabase mydb

   public PrometheusMonitor() {}

   public void initializeMonitor(MeterRegistry registry) {
     meterRegistry = registry;
   }
}
```

Then in your class you can do something like:

```
@Service class MyService {
  @Autowire
  private PrometheusMonitor monitor;

  @PostConstruct
  privte void init() {
    MeterRegistry registry = getRegistry();
    monitor.initializeMonitor(registry);
  }
}
```

2) Create a `MeterRegistry` Bean for your argumented constructor

```
@Bean
public MeterRegistry registry() {
   return getRegistry();
}
```

Then during creation of your PrometheusMonitor it will autowire the registry for the argument when you autowire the mintor

Comment: https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/